# jupyter notebook not working: Error loading page

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, minikube

I'm trying to run jupyter notebook in minikube, so when i execute this command : `kubectl port-forward jupyter-0 -n jupyter 80:80` i get this :

```
Unable to listen on port 80: Listeners failed to create with the following errors : Error tcp4 127.0.0.1:80 : bind : permission deined
```

So i tried another solution witch is this :
`kubectl exec -it jupyter-0 -n jupyter bash`

and then i runned jupyter notebook but this is what i get :
[image]

i changed the port from 80 to 8888 and 9000 with `jupyter notebook --port 9000` but nothing change , how can we solve this ?

Comment: Hello Monica, could you please add your yaml? What is your use-case here if I may ask? Run the notebook in a deployment pod?

Comment: @invertedOwlCoding i can't checkthe yaml file cuz i deployed jupyter with helm chart